# Adding a registry key in Windows 8.1 to enable downloading test drivers

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, drivers, windows-registry

I am trying to enable downloading test drivers on my Windows 8.1. [The tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/br230770.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) says that I should add the following key to the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Test Drivers - use at own risk
```

I think i should:

1) go into HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\ in the regedit

2) right click on Windows then New->Key

3) name the key "Test Drivers"

4) click on new key Test drivers and set "Value data" into "use at own risk"

Am I correct? Would be also nice if you could tell me if it can be done from the command line (it's easier). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the correct thing to do is to right click on `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows` and select New => Key and name it `Test Drivers - use at own risk`

To add it from the Command Line, you have to:

Paste this into a file and name it `import.reg`

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Test Drivers - use at own risk]
"1"="1"
"1"=-
```

Then, simply save and run.